# Invalid read - Valgrind and C

Tags: c, arrays, memory, memory-management, valgrind

New to C and Valgrind and manual memory management and I'm having trouble locating an error that I'm getting when I run Valgrind. I have this function which gets strings from the user:

```
char **get_fragments_from_user(){
    // No more than 20k strings containing at most 1k characters
    char **strings = malloc(20000 * sizeof(char *));

    char tempstring[MAX_INPUT]; //MAX_INPUT = 1001
    int count = 0;
    while(true){
        printf("\n> ");
        fgets(tempstring, MAX_INPUT, stdin);
        if((strlen(tempstring) > 0) && (tempstring[strlen(tempstring) - 1] == '\n')){
            tempstring[strlen(tempstring) - 1] = '\0';
        }
        if(tempstring[0] == 'q') break;
        strings[count] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(tempstring)+1));
        strcpy(strings[count], tempstring);
        count++;
    }
    int i = 0;
    char **fstrings = malloc((count)*sizeof(char *)); // count+1 needed? Something I tried removing while debugging
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++){
        fstrings[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(strings[i])+1));
        strcpy(fstrings[i], strings[i]);
        free(strings[i]);
    }
    free(strings);
    return fstrings;
}
```

The idea here is simply to get strings and put them in an array. I initially allocate an array that is large enough to fit the maximum number of strings that could ever be entered (20,000), but I then resize the array so that I don't allocate more memory than the each string needs. I am a little embarrassed with the above code, since its less clean than anything I would have written in another language, but that was my first pass through.

I then get "Invalid read of size 8" from Valgrind when I try to calculate the number of strings in the array using this function:

```
int lengthOf(char **arr){
    int i = 0;
    while(arr[i] != NULL){
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}
```

I'm pretty sure this is due to a dereferenced pointer or something, but I can't find it for the life of me and I've been looking at this code for an hour or so.

Comment: suggestion, `char **fstrings = calloc(count+1, sizeof(char *));`

Comment: Plus: before `return fstrings;` -->> `fstrings[i] = NULL;`

Comment: Okay, so going to count+1 and making malloc into calloc has gotten rid of the original issue I was having, but I'm now having some other issues, but I'll see if I can work through them first. Another invalid read of size 1.

Comment: @wildplasser: Why do that? My intuition is that it ensures that the lengthOf function will work correctly, but I'm not entirely sure if that's correct.

Comment: The lengthof() functioun counts untill it sees a NULL in the array. You did not put a NULL in there, so whay should there be one?

Comment: Using calloc actually fixes that bug as the memory is 0 initialised

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I believe the problem was that I wasn't allocating enough memory to store the whole array.

Instead of doing:

```
malloc(count * sizeof(char *));
```

I should have been allocating count+1, so either:

```
malloc((count + 1) * sizeof(char *))
```

or

```
calloc((count + 1), sizeof(char *));
```

Comment: There's no apparent need to copy every string twice, you can simply assign the pointers by fstrings[ i] = strings [i] avoiding malloc, strcpy & free in copy loop.  The strings/fstrings need to be terminated by a NULL entry to, so either use calloc, or malloc with assignment to strings[count] = 0 & fstrings[ count].